# Produce a legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

In R I often add legends to my plots like this

```
legend("topright",c("a=1","b=1"),lwd=c(1,2))
```

However, what I want to do is produce a plot which contains **nothing but that legend**. How do I do it? (Preferably without using package such as ggplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a new, empty plot frame using frame() or plot.new()

```
plot.new()
legend("topright",c("a=1","b=1"),lwd=c(1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `type='n'` parameter as in:

```
plot(x,y,type='n')
```

See `?plot.default for details`.  If you will want to add some text/points/lines to the plot afterward you may want to provide the `x` and `y` parameters, and/or the `ylim` and `xlim` parameters in order to set up the plotting region.

You can also drop the axes with the argument `axes=F`, and you can set the `xlab`,`ylab`, and `main` to NA, if you really want a blank plot.